# Multi-line UILabel omits last line sometimes iOS

Tags: ios, uilabel, multiline, uitableview

I am using a multi-line UILabel in a tableview cell with dynamic height. The problem is sometimes, the UILabel omits the last line while the label height is perfect and sometimes it displays everyline perfectly. This is similar to this problem but I have checked that the number of lines are not changing in my case.

[UILabel does not show all my text and it also doesn't show that there is more (...)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7252428/uilabel-does-not-show-all-my-text-and-it-also-doesnt-show-that-there-is-more)

I am implementing UILabel by

1. set lines to 0
2. set word wrap

I then set the text in the Label.

This is the screenshot. The first cell second label shows complete text while the 3rd cell second label does not while the label height is perfect.

[image]

This is the case whether it is a long text of 13-14 lines or just 2 lines. Only the last line is omitted and that too sometimes.

I have also set the preferred width of each of these labels to 220 in nib file of my table view cell.

My code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{




Message *message = [self.messages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

if(indexPath.row % 2 != 0 || indexPath.row == 10)
{
    chatCell = (ChatTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"chatSend"];

    [chatCell.chatMessageLabel setNumberOfLines:0];
    [chatCell.chatNameLabel setNumberOfLines:0];
    [chatCell.chatTimeLabel setNumberOfLines:0];


    chatCell.chatMessageLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    chatCell.chatNameLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    chatCell.chatTimeLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;

    chatCell.chatMessageLabel.text=message.message;
    chatCell.chatNameLabel.text = message.name;
    chatCell.chatTimeLabel.text = message.time;
    chatCell.chatUserImage.image = message.avatar;



}
else
{
    chatCell = (ChatTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"chatReceive"];



    [chatCell.chatMessageLabel setNumberOfLines:0];
    [chatCell.chatNameLabel setNumberOfLines:0];
    [chatCell.chatTimeLabel setNumberOfLines:0];

    chatCell.chatMessageLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    chatCell.chatNameLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    chatCell.chatTimeLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;

    chatCell.chatMessageLabel.text=message.message;
    chatCell.chatNameLabel.text = message.name;
    chatCell.chatTimeLabel.text = message.time;
    chatCell.chatUserImage.image = message.avatar;



    chatCell.authorType = STBubbleTableViewCellAuthorTypeOther;

}


    return chatCell;
}
```

Kindly help!!

Comment: From what I can see/understand the third label (showing "5:00:00") cannot have the right height if you are expecting more than one line. I would recommend ensuring that the correct height is set for the label - showing us that code might help

Comment: I am sorry for the language....I meant to say the third cell and second label and similarly the first visible cell and 2nd label. Both must have same amount of text. One with "That is awesome......."

Comment: Please provide some code snippet of where you're setting up the UILabel in UITableView's `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. Looks like maybe the lines = 0 is not always being set correctly.

Comment: @7usam I have added the code. I have already set the preferred width of each Label to 220 in IB which is what I want. There is no other configuration and setting related to UILabel

Comment: The fact that the text is vertically centered means the label number of lines is either set to 1 or there is only 1 line of text. Make sure the label is holding the correct text (the message.message text is correct) and make sure the label's number of lines isn't changed anywhere else. Check the setter for `chatCell.authorType`. Log the text and number of lines before returning the cell.

Comment: @7usam I did this but could not find out the problem. As you said, here are the log details: `2015-04-16 13:38:03.773 test[1035:44527] That is awesome! I hope people will like that addition.
2015-04-16 13:38:03.773 test[1035:44527] 0
2015-04-16 13:38:12.380 test[1035:44527] That is awesome! I hope people will like that addition.
2015-04-16 13:38:12.381 test[1035:44527] 0`                                                        and the image for this [New Image for this case](http://postimg.org/image/he07col97/)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75379/discussion-between-kerry-and-7usam).

Comment: I am facing a similar issue, in which the last line of the uilable inside a uitableviewcell is not getting displayed. Did you find a solution for this problem of yours?

Comment: Yes, I solved it by using boundwithrect function to find the height of the cell properly. Do take care of the top and bottom constraints of all your views inside the tableview. Let me know if that solved the problem.